# Interpretation of $\mathbf{w^{\top}Cw}$

Tags: interpretation, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

I'm reading a piece on portfolio optimization where it is stated that $\mathbf{w^{\top}Cw}$ is the variance of the expected return, where $\mathbf{C}$ is a covariance matrix and $\mathbf{w}$ is a vector. How can I see that $\mathbf{w^{\top}Cw}$ is indeed a variance?

Comment: What is **w**? What is **C** a covariance matrix of?

Comment: a covariance matrix is positive semidefinite matrix. But other than that, your question needs some more focus. You may check some facts and questions about covariance matrices https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance-matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In portafolio optimization theory, you write the expected return for a portafolio $R_p = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \omega_i R_i$ as:

$$  E[R_p]  = \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \omega_i E[R_i]  $$

where $R_i$ is the return on asset $i$ and $\omega_i$ is a weight.     You can write the variance for the return of the portafolio in matrix notation as

\begin{align}  \mathrm{Var}[  R_p ]  &= E [  \omega^T   R R^T \omega     ]   - E [\omega^T R] (  E[ \omega^T   R ] )^T  \\ 
&= \omega^T \mathrm{Cov}[R] \, \omega  
\end{align}

where $\omega = (\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n)$ and $R = (R_1, \ldots, R_n)$.    In your question, your $\mathbf{C}$ matrix corresponds to $\mathrm{Cov}[R]$.